How to correctly configure NX to work with service workers in a react app?
I have a monorepo where I also ported an existing react app to. The react app is using a service-worker to make sure the app gets updated, but I cannot get it to work in the NX monorepor
My service-worker.js code looks like this:
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';
const version = "1.8.6"
clientsClaim();

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    } // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.

    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    } // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains // a file extension, skip.

    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    } // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.

    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.NX_REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'), // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

// This allows the web app to trigger skipWaiting via
// registration.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'})
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});


A first problem I did encounter was that the service-worker.js gets an error : wrong mimetype
-> So after some research, I did add this to the project josn
.....
 "assets": [
          {
            "input": "apps/guestv1/src/public",
            "glob": "**/*.*",
            "output": "public"
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/guestv1/src/shared/img",
            "glob": "**/*.*",
            "output": "apps/guestv1/src/shared/img"
          },
          "apps/guestv1/src/service-worker.js"
        ],
....

This solved the issue, however I now encounter a new error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at service-worker.js:1:1)
So, it can now find the correct file, however its first needs to be transpiled by webpack / babel
How to add this to the NX configuration? project.json, webpack ...
Here is my current webpack.config
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require("@nx/webpack");
const { withReact } = require("@nx/react");

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(
  withNx(),
  withReact({
    // Uncomment this line if you don't want to use SVGR
    // See: https://react-svgr.com/
    // svgr: false
  }),
  (config) => {
    // Update the webpack config as needed here.
    // e.g. `config.plugins.push(new MyPlugin())`
    return config;
  }
);


I added the service-worker.js to the assets in the project.json
After that, the service-worker was found but got a new error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at service-worker.js:1:1)

Finally, I managed to get it to work ...
I have changed the webpack.config in the following way:
    module.exports = composePlugins(
  withNx(),
  withReact({
    // Uncomment this line if you don't want to use SVGR
    // See: https://react-svgr.com/
    // svgr: false
  }),
  (config) => {
    // Add custom Webpack configuration
    config.entry = {
      ...config.entry,
      'service-worker': './src/service-worker.js', // Add your service worker entry point
    };

    // Optionally, adjust output for service worker
    config.output = {
      ...config.output,
      filename: '[name].js',
    };

    return config;
  }
);

Besides that, I did remove the service-worker from the project.json assets
.....
 "assets": [
          {
            "input": "apps/guestv1/src/public",
            "glob": "**/*.*",
            "output": "public"
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/guestv1/src/shared/img",
            "glob": "**/*.*",
            "output": "apps/guestv1/src/shared/img"
          },
          "apps/guestv1/src/service-worker.js"
        ],
....

After that, verything was working fine.
